# html_entity_decode not working when printing the value in errorLog File

Tags: php

```
<?php

$your_string = "&amp;lt;B&amp;gt;Dirkensock&amp;lt;/B&amp;gt; lidkar 0001 laurate zwart van het merk &amp;lt;B&amp;gt;Dirkensock&amp;lt;/B&amp;gt;. Een leuke lidkar van";

$result = html_entity_decode($your_string,ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
echo  $result ;
errorLog($result);
```

The above code when echo result on browser it prints

```
<B>Dirkensock</B> lidkar 0001 laurate zwart van het merk <B>Dirkensock</B>. Een leuke lidkar van
```

the same if I print in errorlog file it prints as same as the previous

```
&amp;lt;B&amp;gt;Dirkensock&amp;lt;/B&amp;gt; lidkar 0001 laurate zwart van het merk &amp;lt;B&amp;gt;Dirkensock&amp;lt;/B&amp;gt;. Een leuke lidkar van
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
<?php

$your_string = "&amp;lt;B&amp;gt;Dirkensock&amp;lt;/B&amp;gt; lidkar 0001 laurate zwart van het merk &amp;lt;B&amp;gt;Dirkensock&amp;lt;/B&amp;gt;. Een leuke lidkar van";

$result = html_entity_decode($your_string,ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
echo  $result ;
error_Log( html_entity_decode($result) );
```

Output in the log file:

`[Tue Sep 20 08:23:39 2016] [error] [client 192.168.229.40] <B>Dirkensock</B> lidkar 0001 laurate zwart van het merk <B>Dirkensock</B>. Een leuke lidkar van`

For the provided string you have to call `html_entity_decode()` twice. Check the [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) documentation